# REST Api Django - create new model-object and add currently logged in user to it

Tags: django, api, rest

I have an endpoint, where a currently logged in user can create an object called 'project'.

I want to show the user all of his own projects, so when he creates a new one, I want the user to be automatically added to the projects user fields.

How would I achieve that? Both the user and the Project objects do have an ID, so I would like to have an own model which combines those two.

My idea was to create a new view which takes a userID and a projectID and puts them together as ManyToMany relationship. Can I somehow call the view right inside the 'create project' view without the need of a new POST?

I want to be able to use the view at an other point as well, that's why I want to split this.

my current model looks like this

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column = 'db_ID', primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default = None)
    descriptor = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, default = None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Projects'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
class ProjectView(
    APIView,
):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status = 200)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status = 400)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a foreign key to your user object from project like

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can always set the current user by doing this in your serializer

```
serializer = ProjectSerializer(data = request.data, initial={"user": request.user.id} )
```

Comment: or after add user field to your model you can use `serializer.save(user=request.user)`